# How to listen on more than one address in .Net Socket?

Tags: .net, sockets

I need the socket listen on all the addresses pointing my machine, i.e. loop back 127.0.0.1, local address 10.86.xxx.xxx. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try use `IPAddress.Any`.

Answer (score 2):

When you `bind` the socket, if you do not specify an address, it will listen on all. (And monitoring tools will show it listening on 0.0.0.0 (IPv4) or ::0 (IPv6).)

I.e. you need to specify an address to listen on that address, but not specifying an address will listen on all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a system-level hook for TCP/IP events.

Having hooked those events, you have to figure out the contents of the packets you get.

I found some introductory info on hooking Windows events [here](http://www.sdn.nl/SDN/Artikelen/tabid/58/view/View/ArticleID/2187/Hooks-and-Sockets-the-Low-Side-of-VO.aspx).